# file download with temporary link using php

Tags: php

I am working on a project where the user would be able to buy media files. 
after the payment is processed I would like to allow them to download the file. 
I guess it is safe to say that I should have a temporary link to the files. one that is linked to the IP of the user and perhaps a timestamp?
the problem is I dont know where to start with that.
First of all. is this the way to do it? if so..how do I proceed using php. ( i guess I dont need the exact script just hints on how to do it although if there is an existing script I would not mind) 
thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are going to handle the file in PHP you might aswell use a login to check if the user has purchased the file, other than that the code should look a little like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');

$file = new File(intval($_GET['id']));
$fileLocation = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../upload/fileArchive/" . $file->id . "." . $file->type;

header('Content-Length:' . filesize($fileLocation));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".$file->name."\"");

$filePointer = fopen($fileLocation,"rb");
fpassthru($filePointer);
```

*Taken from production and tested*

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't tie the temporary link to an IP, it isn't very user-friendly solution.

Store the purchased media in a table for example:

- Media id (This refers to an another table where the media details described)
- Unique token (This will identificate the purchase)
- Client id
- Total downloads (Maybe you want to enable the download 5 times)
- Token expiry (If you want to limit the access on this)

The download url must contain the unique token and some more data (user's hashed e-mail, etc.) to make the url more unique and more secure.

**Sample URL:** `http://example.com/purchase/nc9o32ocrn8of4nv348/989934ov9344b`

First hash holds the purchase itself while second one identifies the user. On successful identifying you can serve the file like Kristoffer [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575418/file-download-with-temporary-link-using-php/3575563#3575563).

Comment: what about the download page itself. I am not sure how to set it up so the file's locations is hidden. could you please elaborate more on that part?
thanks you

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
$filee = "r.txt";
$fileLocation = dirname(__file__).'/the_sub_folder_for_file/'.$filee;
header('Content-Length:' . filesize($fileLocation));
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".$filee."\"");
$filePointer = fopen($fileLocation,"rb");
fpassthru($filePointer);
```